# How to resolve the problem with PIL.Image getdata() method?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to run the code below:

```
from PIL import Image

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img = Image.open('dddd.tif')

data = img.getdata()
```

but when I compile the last line, I get the message below, and the python prompt exit

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't know what is the exact problem, please if you have the response or if you need more details.

Comment: Is the path to tif image correct? Please check your path ('dddd.tif')

Comment: I did not put the exact path in the question (so as not to weigh down the question). I confirm that I have access to the image with .open(the image path), the problem arises once I type .getdata ()

Comment: maybe its a multiimage tiff file and you are getting all the data that are to big usually you get pixel valuse not entire images

Comment: what does print(img.n_frames) says ???

Comment: getdata() Returns the contents of this image as a sequence object containing pixel values. The sequence object is flattened, so that values for line one follow directly after the values of line zero, and so on.

Comment: print(img.n_frames) give this error   
AttributeError: n_frames

Comment: strange.. are you sure your file is a tiff image ? or better a tiff image pillow can handle. see aroubd https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1659. commented on 2 Mar 2017

There's currently no support for storing anything more than 32bits/pixel.

Comment: can we change title to PIL support for tiff file ?

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do with this type of problem is to check if your version of PIL has support for TIFF files. So, you can run:

```
python -m PIL
```

**Sample Output**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Pillow 8.0.1
Python 3.9.1 (v3.9.1:1e5d33e9b9, Dec  7 2020, 12:10:52)
       [Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Python modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL
Binary modules loaded from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL
--------------------------------------------------------------------
--- PIL CORE support ok, compiled for 8.0.1
--- TKINTER support ok
--- FREETYPE2 support ok, loaded 2.10.4
--- LITTLECMS2 support ok, loaded 2.10
--- WEBP support ok, loaded 1.1.0
--- WEBP Transparency support ok
--- WEBPMUX support ok
--- WEBP Animation support ok
--- JPEG support ok, compiled for 9.0
--- OPENJPEG (JPEG2000) support ok, loaded 2.3.1
--- ZLIB (PNG/ZIP) support ok, loaded 1.2.11
--- LIBTIFF support ok, loaded 4.1.0
*** RAQM (Bidirectional Text) support not installed
*** LIBIMAGEQUANT (Quantization method) support not installed
--- XCB (X protocol) support ok
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The next thing to do is check what happened when you opened the file - did you successfully load an image or not, and is it of a type readable by PIL:

```
im = Image.open('a.tif')

print(im)
<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGB size=10x10 at 0x7FC1A1390B50>
```

If you still have problems, `exiftool` is your friend and will tell you all about your TIF:

```
exiftool a.tif
```

**Sample Output**

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 12.00
File Name                       : a.tif
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 864 bytes
File Modification Date/Time     : 2021:09:06 16:42:30+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:09:06 16:42:31+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2021:09:06 16:42:30+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : TIFF
File Type Extension             : tif
MIME Type                       : image/tiff
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Image Width                     : 10
Image Height                    : 10
Bits Per Sample                 : 16 16 16
Compression                     : Uncompressed
Photometric Interpretation      : RGB
Fill Order                      : Normal
Strip Offsets                   : 8
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Samples Per Pixel               : 3
Rows Per Strip                  : 10
Strip Byte Counts               : 600
Planar Configuration            : Chunky
Page Number                     : 0 1
White Point                     : 0.3127000034 0.3289999962
Primary Chromaticities          : 0.6399999857 0.3300000131 0.3000000119 0.6000000238 0.150000006 0.05999999866
Image Size                      : 10x10
Megapixels                      : 0.000100
```

---

My guess would be that you do not have `libtiff` installed and your image is compressed - check with `exiftool` as above.

> Pillow reads and writes TIFF files. It can read both striped and tiled images, pixel and plane interleaved multi-band images. If you have libtiff and its headers installed, Pillow can read and write many kinds of compressed TIFF files. If not, Pillow will only read and write uncompressed files.

---

If indeed your TIFF is compressed, you have a few options:

- install `libtiff`, or
- use [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/) package, or
- convert your TIFF to uncompressed with **ImageMagick** in Terminal (this will likely make it larger):

  `magick COMPRESSED.TIF -compress none UNCOMPRESSED.TIF`
- convert your compressed file to uncompressed with `tiffutil`

  `tiffutil -none COMPRESSED.TIF -out UNCOMPRESSED.TIF`